# How to insert text field to javafx table view header?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a simple sample of javafx that have a `tableView`. I want to insert a text field under the column header label to filtering table data.

I find an example for this, but it inserts text field instead of header label, while I want to have both of label and text field:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithTextHeaders extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName"));
        TableColumn searchCol = new TableColumn<>();

        TableView table = new TableView();
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams")
        ));

        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;");
        layout.getChildren().add(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        for (Node n: table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label")) {
            if (n instanceof Label) {
                Label label = (Label) n;
                TextField textField = new TextField(label.getText());                
                label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
                label.setGraphic(textField);
                label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }  

    public static class Person {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
        public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); }
        public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
        public void setLastName(String fName) { lastName.set(fName); }
    }
}
```

However I want to do this to some of columns, not to all. How to do this?

Comment: What exacly is it you're asking? What's the intented behaviour?

Comment: I have a tableView component that contain some data. I want to insert a textField to bottom of label of each column in table to filter tables'data based on that column. now how can i do this(how to insert this textField to header of columns)???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to get your hands dirty with the lookup. Just set a graphic on the `TableColumn`:

```
TextField headerTextField = new TextField();
Label label = new Label("First Name");
VBox headerGraphic = new VBox();
headerGraphic.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
headerGraphic.getChildren().addAll(label, headerTextField);

TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>();
firstNameCol.setGraphic(headerGraphic);
```

Comment: very very very very very thanks my friend.it worked very good . good luck