# How to wrap a node (combobox or textfield) with a table column?

Tags: javafx

I have a table with 5 columns. I have comboboxes and textfields which will take user input. When the user submits it, the data gets added to the table. I have a requirement where I need to place these comboboxes and textfields on top of the corresponding table columns. If I drag the table column or the entire table itself, the comboboxes and textfields also should adjust itself according to the table header length. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at the following Solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853621/multiple-components-in-one-column-of-javafx-tableview

Comment: You can make the controls part of the table column header, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794036/how-to-insert-text-field-to-javafx-table-view-header